# How to display both XML and HTML in php?

Tags: php, html, json, xml

-MY GOAL is to display the html tags "My page and TESTING on the page" on the same page.

-If I remove the html tags. It give me the XML.[image]

-If I removed the header('Content-type: text/xml'); I get only the html and not the xml.
[image]

HOW CAN I HAVE BOTH IN THE SAME PAGE.

```
The code is as follows:

<?php
$test_array = array (
  'bla' => 'blub',
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'overflow' => 'stack',
 );
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
 array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
ob_start();
print $xml->asXML();
$xml_output = ob_get_clean();
//header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml_output;
?>
<?php // New PHP block for HTML content ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TESTING</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

/****Another try was****/
TO put the header as header('Content-type: text/json'); //JSON
but here I get the problem whereby it prints the whole html tags
[image]

THIS WOULD ALSO BE GOOD FOR ME, IF AM ABLE TO SOLVE THIS

Comment: if you want to render xml you'll need an xslt to style it. also sincne xhtml is a subset of xml, just use `content-type: text/xml` and it'll display both.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix different content types in a single response.

You output a HTML page that displays the other content. However formatting/styling/interaction would all be your job. You need to escape the included content for HTML - like any other variable.

```php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0">
<foo>
  <bar/>
<foo>
XML;

echo '<h1>Example</h1>';
echo '<pre><code class="language-xml">', htmlspecialchars($xml), '</code></pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

restructuring this a bit:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TESTING</h1>
<pre>
<?php
$test_array = array (
  'bla' => 'blub',
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'overflow' => 'stack',
 );
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML());
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Should give you this in your browser:
[result in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ3if.png)

The `<pre>`-Tag tells the browser that this is preformatted text and the `htmlspecialchars()` makes sure to replace `<` and `>` (open and closing brackets) with HTML entities so that the browser won't try to interpret this as HTML-Tags, but just as plain text.

Hope this helps!

Some links that might be of interest:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre
- https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score -2):

If you just need to display html with xml (with tags), use this

```
<h1>Test html header</h1>
<?php
$string =
"
<root>
    <blub>
        <example_value>EXAMPLE</example_value>
    </blub>
</root>
";
echo '<pre>', htmlentities($string), '</pre>';
?>
```